# Metamask API - Ethereum Transaction Value?

Tags: ethereum

I am using metamask's API for sending-ethereum transactions through my website: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/sending-transactions.html

They require a "value" parameter which is the amount of Ethereum to send to a specific address. How would I send 0.075 Ethereum when they require "hexadecimal values"?

Answer (score 0):

The `value` parameter specifies the amount of wei (smallest ETH unit) - there's 10^18 wei in 1 ETH.

Which makes 0.075 ETH == 75000000000000000 wei.

This number can be converted to hex value 0x10a741a46278000.

JS snippet:

```
(75000000000000000).toString(16)
```